# Fetch rows in MySQL which are not present in both columns from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables with details as mentioned below in MySQL:

TABLE 1:

```
+-------------+---------------+
 | user_id     |  isactive     |
 +-------------+---------------+
 | aaa         | 0             |
 +-------------+---------------+
 | bbb         | 0             | 
 +-------------+---------------+
```

TABLE 2:

```
 +-------------+---------------+-----------+
 |store_no     |  owner        | store     |
 +-------------+---------------+-----------+
 |1234         | aaa           | aaa,xyz   |
 +-------------+---------------+-----------+
 |1006         | aaa           | aaa       | 
 +-------------+---------------+-----------+
 |1005         | ccc           | www       | 
 +-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I need to fetch rows from table 1 whose entries are neither in 'owner' nor in 'store' column of table 2. For example, in the above scenario, the resultset should contain 'bbb'. 
I tried using find_in_set, locate etc but could not fetch the details as required. Please help..

Updated Tables format

Query:

```
select a.user_id from table1 u
left outer join table2 a
on (owner=user_id or concat(',',store,',') like concat('%,',user_id,',%'))
where (find_in_set(user_id,owner) = 0 or find_in_set(user_id,store) = 0)
and  isactive=0
```

FYI, store column can have concatenated values of more than one userid

Comment: Edit your question and add your attempt to solve it.

Comment: select a.user_id from table1 u left outer join table2 a on (owner=user_id or concat(',',store,',') like concat('%,',user_id,',%'))
  where (find_in_set(user_id,owner) = 0 or find_in_set(user_id,store) = 0) and  isactive=0

Comment: normalise your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
T1.user_id
FROM TABLE_1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM 
    TABLE_2 T2
    WHERE T2.owner = T1.user_id OR FIND_IN_SET(T1.user_id,T2.store) > 0
);
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c950/1/0)

**Suggestion:**

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Sounds good. You can also check the fiddle that  I've added just now.

Comment: @HarikaB It may 'solve the issue', but it's hardly a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following :-

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT owner FROM table2) AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(user_id, (SELECT store FROM table2));
```

Second option :-

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT owner FROM table2) AND FIND_IN_SET(user_id, (SELECT store FROM table2)) = 0;
```

It may help you.

Comment: can you please try this solution?

Comment: Thank you for the response. But "select store from table2" would return multiple rows..and therefore throw error

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
select user_id
from table1
where user_id not in
  (select owner from table2)
and not find_in_set(user_id,
  (select store from table2)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But "select store from table2" would return multiple rows..and therefore throw error